# In Qt/C++, is there a way to connect a list of button click events to one slot?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

In Qt/C++, I have a series of buttons where I want to run them through one single event handler for the click, and know which one was clicked.

Is there a way to connect a list of button click events to one slot? As in, I create a `QList<QPushButton *>`, and then use a single `connect()` statement to handle this list's `&QPushButton::clicked` signals, and map this to one single `SLOT(onButtonClicked(QWidget *))`.

Keyword there -- single. Sure, I can iterate a list, but I want to know if there's a way to have only one `connect()` statement that's outside the list iteration.

In other words, I'm wanting to know if there's already an efficient way to do this that I may not realize, rather than me iterating a `QList` of `QPushButton`. It's just a matter of being efficient and tidy.

Comment: You have an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963904/is-there-a-tidier-way-to-connect-many-qt-widgets-of-different-types-to-the-same).

Comment: @Tarod Not exactly. I was looking for a tidier way that was outside the iteration, not inside it. As in somehow pass the entire list of buttons to a connect() call without an iteration.

Comment: I don't think there is such a way. You will always have to establish individual connection of each button either through a signal mapper, or directly to the slot.

Comment: You can create 1 slot without any arguments and use a `sender()` method  + `qobject_cast` inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to handle this would probably to have a `QButtonGroup`. If you insist using a List of your own or may have different widgets or signals, you still could work with an `QSignalMapper`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html